# Pi 3 + Microstack GPS communication

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpsd, raspberry-pi3

I bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, a microstack baseboard and a microstack GPS.

I followed the instructions written in the official documentation but I can't connect to the GPS.

Basically, the GPS led flashes so it means it has find a gps fix, but I can't see any data from the PI.

For example, if I try

```
cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I get always nothing. I already used raspi-config to disable kernel serial and to enable i2c and spi.

Also if I try

```
stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 ispeed 4800 && cat </dev/ttyAMA0"
```

I get an error.

Anyone has any advice, please?

Or maybe these modules are not compatible with Pi 3?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If gpsd were running and the device located at `/dev/ttyAMA0` you would be told   `cat: /dev/ttyAMA0: Device or resource busy`It seems one or both cases warrant investigation.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

On the Pi 3, there are more steps to use serial, you have to disable the BT.

Edit config file:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Add this at the bottom:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt-overlay
```

Then run this:

```
sudo systemctl disable hciuart
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard telling what has been done, or not done.  The ['official' documentation from Microstack](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1860443.pdf) provides two methods of setting up the serial port.  It then continues with

> Automatically Starting gpsd
>   To automatically start the gps service when the Raspberry Pi® boots, re­configure the GPS 
>   daemon by typing into a terminal
>   `sudo dpkg-­reconfigure gpsd`
>
> ● Choose `<yes>`  when asked if you want to start gpsd  automatically.
>   ● Choose `<no>`  when asked “should gpsd handle attached USB GPS 
>   receivers automatically” .
>   ● When asked which “Device the GPS receiver is attached to” , enter 
>   `/dev/ttyAMA0` .
>   ● Accept the defaults for other options.

If you have configured your serial port as per instructions *and* configured gpsd to automagically start and pick up the device you have just setup, ...then, since the gpsd is handling the device (right?), the device will be busy and the command `cat /dev/ttyAMA0`  **should** return `cat: /dev/ttyAMA0: Device or resource busy`...but, it did not.

Either the serial is not configured *as per instructions*, or the gpsd is not running and picking up the device, or both.

The goal is not to `cat` your gps data, but the `cat` not returning an *error* indicates something is amiss.

Typically, it's just a typo.  But it can be from skipping a step in the process, or mixing instructions from various sources so that the left hand doesn't know what the right hand has done.

Try:
`sudo killall gpsd` if it returns `gpsd: no process found` that answers one question.

If it returns with no error, follow it up with `cat /dev/ttyAMA0`. If it returns nothing, the direction you should look is your serial port configuration.

If `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd` is not allowing you to reconfigure (I thought it was just me) you can modify the configuration of gpsd by using your favourite editor, e.g. `sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd` and entering something like:

```
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.

# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="true"

# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="false"

# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/dev/ttyAMA0"

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G"
```

You may find the `-n` and -`G` useful.  Save and restart.

Comment: thanks a lot. the problem is that if I try sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd, it will not ask me any option, just print some info about a gpsd account and start the service again

Comment: if I try sudo-reconfigure gpsd I get: Warning: Stopping gpsd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  gpsd.socket
Creating/updating gpsd user account...

Comment: @GavynSykes I've added gpsd configuration to the answer

Answer (score 0):

This article was very usefull for me

http://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/#comment-67160

and i recommand you to read it

Now on RPI3 the Serial port

ttyAMA0 is used by BlueTooth
ttySO refers to the GPIO
The Alias Serial0 refers to the GPIO both on RPI2 and RPI3.
So :

after a reinstallation of Jessie with a recent version to be sure all is clean

as usual

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo  raspi-config
```

go to Advanced options : Would you like a login shell to be accessible over serial? response "yes" (not as in the microstack datasheet )

```
$ sudo apt-­get install python3-­microstacknode
```

To install the gpsd standard tools

```
$ sudo apt­-get install gpsd gpsd-­clients python­-gps
```

edit GPSD by

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd
```

and put the options :

```
START_DAEMON="true"
USBAUTO="false"
DEVICES="/dev/serial0"
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G"
```

equally

```
$ sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

remove

console=serial0,115200 
and save

```
$ sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

you must have at the end

```
enable_uart=1
```

Disable the console by

```
$ sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
$ sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

i have equally done  `$ sudo chmod 775 ../../dev/ttySO` ( i dont know if it is really necessary )

and obviously a reboot

and miracle the gps works with

```
cgps -s
```

NB: you must have a fix on the GPS ( the red led flashes )

jpherrenknecht